# A formula for a unitary matrix

Tags: unitary-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

Proposition: U = (H+iI)(H-iI)^-1 is unitary if H is self-adjoint.  I'm having trouble finding a proof.  It's straightforward if (H-iI) and (H+iI)^-1 commute.  But I don't see it.

Comment: $H\pm iI$ are invertible. Moreover $\|(H-iI)x\|^2=\|(H+iI)x\|^2.$ The factors in $U$ indeed commute, as $H-iI$ and $H+iI$ commute.

Comment: To overkill, the $C^*$-algebra generated by self-adjoint $H$ must be commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Actually while it's straightward to establish $H+iI$ and $H-iI$ commute, it's unnecessary. To show $\|(H+iI)(H-iI)^{-1}x\|=\|x\|$ for all $x$, since $H-iI$ is invertible (as $H$ is self-adjoint, $i$ is not in its spectrum), it suffices to show $$\forall y, \|(H+iI)(H-iI)^{-1}(H-iI)y\|=\|(H-iI)y\|$$ $$\|(H+iI)y\|=\|(H-iI)y\|$$